# Comparing two sequences of numbers from within a file efficiently execution time wise

Tags: c++, mingw

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
ifstream f("Bac.txt");
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,m,i,j,ok,nr=0;
    long v[100],p[100];
    f>>m;
    f>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
        f>>p[i];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        f>>v[i];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        ok=0;
        for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
        {
            if(v[i]==p[j])
                ok=1;
        }
        if(ok==0)
            nr++;
    }
    cout<<nr;

}
```

"Bac.txt" file contains:

6 7

1 2 3 4 7 20

3 5 7 8 9 20 24

This program that I made compares the values of 2 arrays read from within a file, and displays the number of values that are unique to the second array, when compared to the first.

Is the method I am using efficient "execution time-wise" to any extent ? Would it be more efficient if I would not store the number sequences on the 2nd and 3rd line of the file into arrays, or is it even possible to make the program do the same thing like that ? (or would that only make it more efficient from a storage memory point of view, but not also execution time-wise ? )

Comment: also, why are you indexing from 1?  You got a thing against the 0th slot in the arrays?  for (i = 0; i < m;i++) is what you really want.

Comment: it's just how I've been taught to index arrays like, and I'm used to it like that...it's the same thing anyway as long as I go >=n with the index

Comment: It's really not cool to use 1-based arrays in C++.  The language uses 0-based arrays.  You should get used to it, or you will just end up confusing yourself and anyone who works with your code.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that you have been taught wrong then  It's not a huge thing but every other C programmer in the world starts from zero and your code will just annoy people.  It's a small mental change so just make it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is currently **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**, which is not particularly great.

If the two sequences are sorted, you can do this in **O(N)** time by simply merging the two arrays.

If the two sequences are not sorted, you can do it in **O(N.logN)** time by using `std::set`.